# Outlook link preview breaking "one time URL"

Tags: php, outlook, token

I made a one time URL system, that has a token that becomes invalid once the user accesses that URL.

I send the email to the client with the URL containing the token, when he commits a form.

It works fine for people who uses Gmail and whatnot. However, many of the clients who use Hotmail complained that always when they clicked the URL even for the first time, it was already invalid.

I ended up finding out that Outlook has a Link Preview function, enabled by default, that display a little preview of the links in the email. Since this function accesses the URL once, the token becomes invalid when the client opens the email.

Is there a way in PHP to detect if the access to a URL is being done by a link preview system? That way I could make the token invalid only when the access was not made by a link preview.

Comment: You could check the User Agent string on the server and see if it matches any of these email clients.

Comment: What _exactly_ is the purpose of this token, what specific action needs to happen only once?

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă The only different thing in User Agent I found was "BingPreview". I may try use this to invalidate the token only when the string doesn't contain "BingPreview", but I wonder if: all link preview systems (if other than Outlook have one) use it too; and if "BingPreview" is used by other stuff/browsers.

CBroe, it's a link to a payment page. One time URL being used to avoid the risk of multiple payments for the same product.

Comment: I have the same problem. I send a feedback request email to clients where they are asked to provide a one-click rating of the job we did for them by clicking on 1 out of the 10 links contained in the email (corresponding to satisfaction levels: 10% 20% 30% etc.). It has happened, that this link-preview feature caused false ratings, i.e., Outlook previewed any of those 10 links. Did your filtering of BingPreview resolve the problem? Is there any other piece of code that we can add to a link to prevent this preview from happening? Like "rel=nofollow" or something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The outlook preivew request is using [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request here. You can check the  request type and do not invalidate your link with HEAD request.

(A better solution will be stopping triggering any logic with a simple GET request. You can create a button instead of link to ask users to click. Preview bot is unlikely to click a button like users.)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not true - the MicrosoftPreview bot links coming from hotmail are a standard GET request, at least according to my nginx logs.

Comment: Is a refer url being sent? Any other http headers that might be useful?